# Rails render partial from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, partial

I'm trying to render different partials into my index view from the controller, depending on the params I receive.
I have a simple unless-else condition inside my controller that checks the params

```
def index
 unless params[:check].nil?
  render :partial => /layout/check
 else
  render :partial => /layout/not_check
 end
end
```

And I have the files _check.html.erb and not_check.html.erb into the folder layout/

Now, how can I show that partials inside my index view?
At the moment I can just visualize the partial alone as a single view, but not inside the requested view.

Comment: put rendering code into index.html.erb

Comment: llayout are views but they have some common UI. generally, All different layouts must be placed under app/views/layouts/. the partials _check and _not_check should reside inside ur controller views

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The better way would be to call the partials from index.html.erb

```
<% unless params[:check].nil? %>
  <%= render :partial => '/layout/check' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render :partial => '/layout/not_check' %>
<% end %>
```

so your def index would look like this

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

I did not understand what you are trying to do but partial which are related to controller/actions should not be in layout unless they are serving some layout.

Comment: Please review ERB and Ruby in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to render a layout (and not actual view information) try using [render layout](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)

```
def index
  if params[:check].nil?
    render layout: "not_check"
  else
    render layout: "check"
  end
end
```